# Parsing web page text content and viewing in <div> with same formation

Tags: php, regex, html

Here I am parsing page text:

```
<?php
$url= 'http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}
$textContent = $doc->textContent; //inherited from DOMNode
$text=escapeshellarg($textContent);
$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($text));

echo $test; //This gives entire content in one line loosing actual page text format
echo echo nl2br($textContent);  // This does not show in single line but some un usual form. 

?>
```

i also tried with `<pre>` tag but it also shows entire content in single line.
What change here so that I can get paragraph with break line as in original page?

I only want text content no image, buttons and all.

Comment: Try putting `\n` in the negated character class.

Comment: why are you using `escapeshellarg`?

Comment: this [^a-zA-Z]+ just removes everything what is not letter. I suggest do replace in several steps. First change <br> into \r\n or \n. Second remove html tags /<.+?>/ and third all other what you want.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: It is necessary for me. As I am taking entire content as a string parameter and passing it to my program

Comment: @Darka: you noted correctly. But I could not implement it. If you please add it in your answer then really greateful and I can mark as my answer.

Comment: @Karimkhan what do you mean you can't implement?

Comment: @Darka: I already tried, but with no success!

Comment: Just tellm me `preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+[/n]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($text));` is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

what if you replace:

```
$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($text));
```

to

```
$test = preg_replace("/<br>/", "\r\n", html_entity_decode($text));
$test = preg_replace("/<.+?>/", " ", $test);
$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\r\n]+/", " ", $test);
```

Comment: thanks but can you please add explaination. Here you have not included a-z then where it will be considered?

Comment: why you want to use it? if you want to use it, look updated answer.

Comment: @Darpa: still it does not give expected result.

Comment: check this:
`
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url= 'http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($xpath->query("//script") as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}

$textContent = $doc->textContent; //inherited from DOMNode

$text=escapeshellarg($textContent);
   $test = preg_replace("/<br>/", "\r\n", html_entity_decode($text));
   $test = preg_replace("/<.+?>/", " ", $test);

echo $test; ?>`

Comment: Darka: Thanks a lot for your effort. But Update answer also gives single line as a result.

Comment: where you looking result? in page or console?

Comment: so maybe you can change all \r\n to <br>. Like this : $test = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n/", "<br />", $test);